# Spring Integration error channel in gateways

Tags: spring-integration

I have a rest controller that will trigger my gateway method

```
<int:gateway id="bGatewayService"
        service-interface="nd.l.eai.gw.BGateway"
        default-reply-channel="dest-channel"
        default-request-timeout="5000" default-reply-timeout="5000">        
        <int:method name="m1" request-channel="atbInChannel"/>
        <int:method name="m2" request-channel="btuInChannel"/>
    </int:gateway>
```

the application works ok. I don't have error-channel [as you see above]

My question is - what is the advantage of the error-channel, as I am getting the 500 or Bad Request without it. Should I create an error channel and include in the above?

Also I am using default reply channel, is that ok? or should I add reply-channel to each method? I have another gateway that has 10 methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `error-channel` if you are not going to have some *compensation flow*. If just throw an exception as is OK with your use-case, then don't configure any `error-channel`.

In most cases we don't need a `reply-channel` as well, even that `default-reply-channel`. When you don't use an `output-channel` in the last endpoint of your flow, the `replyChannel` header is going to be use. We only need that `reply-channel` for use-cases where we need some kind of pub-sub reply message processing, where we would like to send a reply message not only as a return for gateway method call, but also to some other flow.

More info is in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#gateway

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do; the error channel allows you to analyze the error and return different results based on the exception.

E.g. you can ask them to try again for a transient error or report the problem for a fatal error in the request.

The reply channel is generally not needed unless you want to do something like add a wire tap to log the reply. In fact, that channel ends up being bridged to the replyChannel header in the request (which is how the gateway correlates requests/replies.